# Truncate text of flexbox child

Tags: html, css, flexbox, tailwind-css

I'm trying to do a simple layout like this:

[image]

the text should be truncated. In the following example it works: if you resize the window, the text is truncated.

```css
.page {
  max-width: 1200px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 0px 5px;
  background-color: Cornsilk;
}

.logo {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.content-container {
  min-width: 0px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}

.bar-container {
  width: 100%;
}

.bar {
  width: 40%;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: black;
}

.text-container {
}

.truncate {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.value-container {
  width: 50px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="logo"></div>

    <div class="content-container">
      <div class="bar-container">
        <div class="bar"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="text-container truncate">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="value-container">
      1234
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

but when I use Tailwind, something goes wrong:

[tailwind playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/LS7w7Z30rb?size=590x720)

what's the problem here? I didn't understand

Comment: In the playground example, if you remove `flex-wrap` it resolves it. https://play.tailwindcss.com/zQCfPl0Hqk?size=590x720